# Unable to read image in tmp in gcloud through cv2.imread(), it returns none

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud, opencv, imread, python

I am trying to read an image from my tmp folder in my gcloud django app for further face detection processing but my cv2.imread() function returns none when i provide it with my file path as the arguement. there is no problem in my file path as i have tested it.

```
...
im = cv2.imread("/tmp/" + pathname)
print("IMAGE IS ", im)                #returns IMAGE IS None
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
...
```

Error I Get

> OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error:
>   (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Tested file existence using the following piece of code:

```
if os.path.exists("/tmp/" + pathname):
       print("IMAGE EXISTS !") //returns this
else:
       print("IMAGE DOESNT EXISTS !")
```

Answer (score 1):

The filepath is the problem.  The `cv2.imread` won't show an error when you enter an invalid image path.  Have you tried without the / in front of the tmp?

```
pathname = "image.jpg"
im = cv2.imread("tmp/"+pathname)
print("IMAGE IS ", im)  
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: but now i solved my problem using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211221/how-do-i-use-cv2-imread-on-a-file-stored-in-google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib

url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVWX7.jpg";
resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

**I SOLVED IT USING THIS APPROACH**

To convert gs to normal URL.

```
bucket = 'example-bucket'
file = 'sunset.jpg'

gcs_url = 'https://%(bucket)s.storage.googleapis.com/%(file)s' % {'bucket':bucket, 'file':file}

print gcs_url
```